# Angular module development alongside main application

Tags: angular, npm, ngrx-store

Let's say I have a main web application and a mobile (ionic) application that I would like to share the same ngrx/store.

I've been able to break the ngrx/store out into a separate module that we can include in our projects using npm.

However, the side-effect of this is that now, when I want to change something in the store, I have to open the other project, change it there, re-publish to npm and pull it back into my project.

I own only the Ionic application and the store, so I would really like to pull the actual code into my development environment and build/debug directly against the store module. Then I could publish out to npm only when it reaches as stable state. The other developer (of the main web application) could then pull the code from npm and use it.

Could anyone give me any advice on keeping both the module and ionic project together, but still allowing the module to be simple to build and publish to npm?

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Hal

Answer (score 1):

Use npm link to link your module to your development folder.